# A question about epsilon delta continuity.

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

We know that the if a function $f$ is continuous in a point $a$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta >0$ such that if $$|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$
But note that in this definition we already assume that $f(a)$ exists, in other words the function is well defined in the point $a$, which mean that the definition works only with jump discontinuity and infinite discontinuity .

This is what i understand from this definition.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is about the validity of my understanding about the definition. @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In words: a function is continuous at a point if it is defined at that point and it has a limit at that point that agrees with its value.

That's just what the formal definition says.

If a function is not defined at a point it can't be continuous there, so this definition is correct when the graph has a vertical asymptote so is not defined.

It's also correct at what looks like a jump discontinuity. If the function is defined at the jump point its value can't be the limit there.

Comment: Thank you for your elegant explanation @Ethan Bolker

Comment: Though I'd emphasize that while a function can't be continuous at a vertical asymptote, it also isn't discontinuous there. The entire concept of continuity or discontinuity is reserved for points within the domain. $f:\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}\to\mathbb R,~x\mapsto\frac1x$ is a perfectly continuous function, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused with the definition of limit and continuity. While we can talk about the limit of a function at a point where it isn't defined (as long as this point is an accumulation point of the domain) we **can't** talk about continuity for a point that doesn't belong in the domain of the function.

Comment: To drive this point home: talking about continuity of a function at a point outside its domain is like talking about Germany's population density in New York. By its very nature, Germany's population density is only a sensible thing to measure inside Germany's borders. Similarly, by its very nature a function's continuity is only a sensible thing to examine within its domain.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Very nice analogy :)